# printf() intermittently ceasing to print during debugging in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, debugging, printf, stdout, xcode4

I have just upgraded to Xcode 4 and am working in C++ project. I am finding that printf() intermittently fails to complete printing (mid-line) to the Xcode console, and from there on printf() ceases to print anything - even though the application continues to run in debugger.

I suspect Xcode 4's console window is at fault because if I redirect stdout to a file, then logging seems to continue without any problems. That said, if I use following on command line:

> tail -f log-out.txt

then there are times when incomplete lines are shown. But this is probably due to some sort of buffering (incomplete flush) because ultimately the lines are complete in the file.

So, I am wondering if anyone has experienced something like this and has an understanding of what's causing freeze in Xcode's console output.

Comment: Yes, and I've seen similar things in Xcode 3 from time to time. I don't know of a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems to be intermittent and reportedly pre-exists Xcode 4. As a work-around I did something like this to the main() function. There are some advantages to this approach when Xcode's Debug Console is misbehaving.

```
#define REDIRECT_STDOUT_TO_FILE 1

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
#if REDIRECT_STDOUT_TO_FILE //## redirect stdout to "log-out.txt"
    freopen("log-out.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif  //  REDIRECT_STDOUT_TO_FILE

    MyApp app(argc, argv);

    int result = app.Run();

#if REDIRECT_STDOUT_TO_FILE //## redirect stdout to "log-out.txt"
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(stdout);
#endif  //  REDIRECT_STDOUT_TO_FILE

    return result;
}
```

Using **tail -f log-out.txt** in Terminal allows one to view stdout output. Or, if you use BBEdit, **bbedit --new-window log-out.txt** is also an workable solution.

For now, I am considering this a bug in Xcode - and I will continue trying to understand under what conditions it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Never actually worked with Xcode, BUT:

Can you show us how your printf calls look like?

The reason why I'm asking is that, if you don't flush your stream, some of the output might not reach the console (as you actually pointed out in the question). The simplest way to do that is to add a newline character at the end of each printf call.

Comment: The printf() lines that are mostly likely to print incompletely all end with '\n'. I have read in other SO posts that newline => flush may result from special behavior in console. Using tail, I see partial lines printed and suspect that the stream's buffer size accounts for this - and not the presence of newlines. But this is just conjecture.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a buffer overflow => stack corruption => something should throw an exception, at least in debug mode? If not, you could do something like: see at which approximate length the output gets truncated, then run two or more calls to printf with an even larger string. Between them manually flush the streams (fflush(NULL); I think). If it's the buffer you should get all the output lines truncated in the same spot. Have you tried using the same arguments for printf on another compiler?

Comment: I think that what I am experiencing is actually a bug in Xcode. I don't say that lightly. But given the fact that by redirecting stdout to a file I no longer see this freeze-like behavior, I have to assume that the problem is not with streaming or buffering, per se. I am using printf() for debugging purposes, so it doesn't really matter to me where the output ends up. In some ways, streaming to a file is better. As for buffer overflow, I am not suggesting that at all. Often streams are implemented to flush when their buffer is full - this what I am probably seeing in file stream.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.